# ROS Answers SE migration: geometry_msg

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi i tired to use catkin_make and its doesnt work , i am really new and need some help,
Thanks for helping

Terminal:

```
(base) adam@adam-VivoBook-S15-X530UN:~/catkin_ws$ catkin_make
Base path: /home/adam/catkin_ws
Source space: /home/adam/catkin_ws/src
Build space: /home/adam/catkin_ws/build
Devel space: /home/adam/catkin_ws/devel
Install space: /home/adam/catkin_ws/install
####
#### Running command: "make cmake_check_build_system" in "/home/adam/catkin_ws/build"
####
-- Using CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX: /home/adam/catkin_ws/devel
-- Using CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH: /home/adam/catkin_ws/devel;/opt/ros/kinetic
-- This workspace overlays: /home/adam/catkin_ws/devel;/opt/ros/kinetic
-- Found PythonInterp: /usr/bin/python2 (found suitable version "2.7.12", minimum required is "2") 
-- Using PYTHON_EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/python2
-- Using Debian Python package layout
-- Using empy: /usr/bin/empy
-- Using CATKIN_ENABLE_TESTING: ON
-- Call enable_testing()
-- Using CATKIN_TEST_RESULTS_DIR: /home/adam/catkin_ws/build/test_results
-- Found gtest sources under '/usr/src/gmock': gtests will be built
-- Found gmock sources under '/usr/src/gmock': gmock will be built
-- Found PythonInterp: /usr/bin/python2 (found version "2.7.12") 
-- Using Python nosetests: /usr/bin/nosetests-2.7
-- catkin 0.7.20
-- BUILD_SHARED_LIBS is on
-- BUILD_SHARED_LIBS is on
-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
-- ~~  traversing 1 packages in topological order:
-- ~~  - agitr
-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'agitr'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(agitr)
CMake Warning at /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:76 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "geometry_msg" with
  any of the following names:

    geometry_msgConfig.cmake
    geometry_msg-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "geometry_msg" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "geometry_msg_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
  "geometry_msg" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it
  has been installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  agitr/CMakeLists.txt:5 (find_package)


-- Could not find the required component 'geometry_msg'. The following CMake error indicates that you either need to install the package with the same name or change your environment so that it can be found.
CMake Error at /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:83 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "geometry_msg" with
  any of the following names:

    geometry_msgConfig.cmake
    geometry_msg-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "geometry_msg" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "geometry_msg_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
  "geometry_msg" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it
  has been installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  agitr/CMakeLists.txt:5 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/adam/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/adam/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
Makefile:542: recipe for target 'cmake_check_build_system' failed
make: *** [cmake_check_build_system] Error 1
Invoking "make cmake_check_build_system" failed
```

package.xml :

```
<package format="2">
<name>agitr</name>
<version>0.0.0</version>
<description>The agitr package</description>
<maintainer email="adam@todo.todo">adam</maintainer>
<license>TODO</license>
<buildtool_depend>catkin</buildtool_depend>
<build_depend>roscpp</build_depend>
<exec_depend>roscpp</exec_depend>
<build_depend>geometry_msgs</build_depend>
<exec_depend>geometry_msgs</exec_depend>
<build_depend>turtlesim</build_depend>
<exec_depend>turtlesim</exec_depend>
>
</package>
```

CMakeList.txt :

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(agitr)
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS roscpp geometry_msg)
catkin_package()
include_directories(${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS})
include_directories()
add_executable(hello hello.cpp)
add_executable(pubvel pubvel.cpp)
target_link_libraries(hello ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/347738/geometry_msg/) by [henoch](https://answers.ros.org/users/52948/henoch/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2020-03-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`geometry_msgs` With an `s`

---

Originally posted by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) with karma: 8272 on 2020-03-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1